# Why is InputMethodManager.isFullscreen() not reliable after app rotation?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am currently working on an app which has a 3 step authentication wizard.

I need to know if the user is editing text in fullscreen so that I can dismiss the keyboard instead of proceeding to the next step in the wizard.

I'm currently facing an annoying problem where the following code returns erroneous results after the activity has rotated.

```
    private boolean isFullscreenInputMode(EditText edit) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)edit.getContext().getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE  );
        return imm.isFullscreenMode();
    }
```

The code is meant to detect if the keyboard is in fullscreen mode and ExtractEditText used for input.

If my app starts out in landscape mode and I continue the entire 3 step wizard this method will return true. If I rotate my phone once along the way it stops working.

NOTE: The call is not performed in a onPause or onResume callback method. As I've understood from other posts these are situations that can result in the method returning the wrong value.

Alternatively, is there another way to detect if the keyboard is in fullscreen mode?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT Adding the editorActionListener code for the "Done" button on the EditText view:**

```
        edit.setOnEditorActionListener( new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction( TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event ) {
            if( actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE && edit.getText().length() >= minKeys ) {

                if( !isFullscreenInputMode(edit) ) {
                    performOkPress( edit, okButton, result );
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void performOkPress( final EditText edit, final Button okButton, final ViewResult result ) {
            if( okButton.isEnabled() ) {
                okPressed( edit, okButton, result );
            }
        }
    } );
```

Comment: When you are rotating the screen, it means you are changing orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa.......and everytime, your onCreate gets called again and again. Which is why you see these Erroneous results.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rotating the screen, it means you are changing orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa.......and everytime, your onCreate gets called again and again. Which is why you see these Erroneous results.Try saving the state of the activity when you rotate...hopefully it helps

Comment: How does that affect the results of what the InputMethodManager returns on the isFullscreen method?

Comment: Especially since this code is only called when an event is triggered and should not be using any saved state.